# iMacros, conditional based on .CSV data

Tags: c#, csv, if-statement, imacros

I'm trying to get iMacros to enter data from a C# generated .CSV file into a webpage.  If one of the fields remains blank, iMacros errors out with

```
"Entry [] not available [Box has 804 entries], line: 24 (Error code: -924):"
```

How can I set iMacros to conditionally enter data ONLY if that .CSV column has data in it?

Here's the code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=ID:procform ATTR=NAME:next
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:procform ATTR=ID:field_900022 CONTENT=${{!COL11}}
```

I tried to use an EVAL command, but it didn't work:

```
SET !${{!COL11}} EVAL("if (\"${{!COL11}}\" != " ")    
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=ID:procform ATTR=NAME:next
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:procform ATTR=ID:field_900022 CONTENT=${{!COL11}};
```

Note: using iMacros free firefox add-on & Visual Studio 2015 C#.  I used a space (" ") in the c# program to hold the CSV field (i.e. "data, data, , more data").  It can very well be another character.
Thanks

Comment: [imacros wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL) suggests the next as a proper syntax for EVAL:

`SET !VAR1 EVAL("[javascript statements]")`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply to ignore errors?

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:procform ATTR=ID:field_900022 CONTENT=${{!COL11}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
```